# Handling set of function created in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am disperating trying to make this code work:

```
var dropzoneId = "drop_zone";

window.addEventListener("dragenter", function(e) {
  if (e.target.id != dropzoneId) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "none";
    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "none";
  }
}, false);

window.addEventListener("dragover", function(e) {
  if (e.target.id != dropzoneId) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "none";
    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "none";
  }
});

window.addEventListener("drop", function(e) {
  if (e.target.id != dropzoneId) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "none";
    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "none";
  }
});

function _(el){
    return document.getElementById(el);
}

function uploadFile(inc, id_prototipo, id_allegato_prototipo, id_pratica, tipo, event){
    if(event === undefined){
    var file = _("file" + inc).files[0];
    }
    else{
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    var file = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
    }
    // alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+" | "+file.type);
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("upfile", file);
    formdata.append("id_prototipo", id_prototipo);
    formdata.append("id_allegato_prototipo", id_allegato_prototipo);
    formdata.append("id_pratica", id_pratica);
    formdata.append("tipo", tipo);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", window["progressHandler"+inc], false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", window["completeHandler"+inc], false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", window["errorHandler"+inc], false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", window["abortHandler"+inc], false);
    ajax.open("POST", "../../classi/upload.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);
}

function create_function(){
    var temp = _("nof");
    nof = temp.value;
    for(j = 0; j < parseInt(nof); j++){
        window["progressHandler"+j] = function(event){
            document.getElementById("loaded_n_total" + j).innerHTML = "Uploaded "+event.loaded+" bytes of "+event.total;
            var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
            document.getElementById("progressBar" + j).value = Math.round(percent);
            document.getElementById("status" + j).innerHTML = Math.round(percent)+"% uploaded... please wait";
            alert();
        }
        window["completeHandler"+j] = function(event){
            document.getElementById("status"+j).innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
            document.getElementById("progressBar"+j).value = 0;
            alert();
        }
        window["errorHandler"+j] = function(event){
            document.getElementById("status"+j).innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
            alert();
        }
        window["abortHandler"+j] = function(event){
            document.getElementById("status"+j).innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
            alert();
        }


        /*window["drag_drop"+j] = function(inc){


        }*/
    }
}
```

I need to create a set of function (I used, f.e. window["errorHandler"+j] in a for cycle),
then I must make sure that they are called back by an event.

The problem is that (let's suppose that nof is 3) the callback of the event works, but it doesn't call the function errorHandler0, but it continues the cycle and call the function errorHandler4, like it is continuing the for cycle.

I am disparated :\
Please, help me

Comment: where are you using the `uploadFile()` method?

Comment: I would recommend you read up on how to program in an object oriented way. Learning proper OOP will make your life a lot easier. Especially in cases like this. Example of learning material: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/an-introduction-to-object-oriented-programming-in-javascript-8900124e316a/

Comment: I call that method through an input field

<input type='file' name='upfile".$inc."' id='file".$inc."' style='display: yes;'><br>
  <div id='drop_zone' onclick='document.getElementById(\"file".$inc."\").click();' ondrop='uploadFile(".$inc.", ".$id_prototipo.", ".$campo['id'].", ".$id_pratica.", ".$campo['tipo'].", event);' ondragover='return false;'>

Comment: Actually, the problem is that instead of calling the function (f.e.) errorHandler1, it calls erroHandler3 (last j index plus 1).
The debugging console shows clearly that the code enters again in the for brackets and recall the last j value.